# Help simplifying double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the surface
$$ 
f(x,y)=y^2-x, 
$$
find the integral over the region bounded by the curves $y=sin(x)$ and $y=cos(x)$ in the interval $0≤x≤\frac{\pi}{4}$.
I set up the double integral as (1) and solved the inner integral to get (2).

$$\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x}y^2-x~\mathsf dy~\mathsf dx \tag 1
\\ 
&\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos (x)^3}3-{x\cos x} -\frac{\sin (x)^3}3+{x\sin x}~\mathsf dx \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Is there a way to simplify this or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Each of the components can be solved by integration by parts, for example

\begin{align} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \sin^3(x) \, dx &= \int_0^\frac\pi4 \sin x ( \sin^2 x) \, dx\\
&=  \left.(- \cos x)( \sin^2 x)\right\vert_{0}^\frac{\pi}{4} - \int_0^\frac\pi4(-\cos x)(2\sin x \cos x) \, dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2\sqrt2} + 2\int_0^\frac\pi4\sin x \cos^2 x \, dx \\
&=  -\frac{1}{2\sqrt2} + 2\int_0^\frac\pi4\sin x (1-\sin^2 x) \, dx \\
&=  -\frac{1}{2\sqrt2} + 2\int_0^\frac\pi4\sin x \, dx - 2\int_0^\frac\pi4\sin^3 x \, dx \\\end{align}

Bringing the last term to the left hand side, we have

$$3 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \sin^3 x \, dx = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt2} + 2\int_0^\frac\pi4\sin x \, dx $$

Hence we should be able to evaluate $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \sin^3 x \, dx$.

Integration of terms  $\int_0^\frac{\pi}4 \cos^3 \, dx$ can also be solved by integration by parts technique shown above.

Terms like $\int x \cos x \, dx$ and $\int x \sin x$ should be direct application of integration by parts.